# Travelling salesman problem

Tags: modeling, vehicle-routing, big-m

[image]

This is a CVRP problem and I have difficulty understanding the constraints in the red box.

For the sub-eliminator constraint (MTZ), my question is how can we make it on our own? I am sure there is some trick.

Comment: What do you mean by “ how can we make it on our own”? Do you mean “how do we implement them in a modelling language” or what is meant by the statement?

Answer (score 2):

The MTZ constraints are big-M constraints that enforce the logical implication
$$x_{ij}=1\implies u_j\ge u_i+d_j.$$
That is, if you traverse arc $(i,j)$, the cumulative demand at $j$ is at least the cumulative demand at $i$ plus the demand at $j$. The basic form is $$u_i+d_j-u_j\le M_{ij}(1-x_{ij}).$$
To find a good value for $M_{ij} $, you want an upper bound on the LHS when $x_{ij}=0$.  Adding the bounds $u_i\le C$ and $-u_j\le -d_j$ yields $$u_i+d_j-u_j\le C+d_j-d_j=C,$$ so take $M_{ij}=C$.